# How to download data non asynchronously?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, download, webclient

I want to download data non asynchronously in a Windows Phone application. I would make a downloader class, and have a simple method in it to download a string from a URL. On other platforms, I would use:

```
 public class TextDownloader
 {
      public string GetString(string url)
      {
           WebClient web = new WebClient();
           string s = web.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
           return s;
      }
 }
```

It would work well: simple, minimal code. However, the `WebClient.DownloadString` method is not available on Windows Phone 7, nor many WebRequest options. Are there any alternative ways to download data non asynchronously in Windows Phone? I would rather not have to create multiple events for download and error, just have a simple method return a value or throw an exception.

Comment: @lelyor, What's that got to do with this question?

Comment: You should use the asynchronous way to avoid blocking your UI thread - this is how things are done on WP nowadays.

Comment: @igrali I know this is a completely old question, but in this situation I would have been calling the synchronous download method on a non UI thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, you cannot use the synchronous model for downloads with `WebClient` out-of-the-box. This is by design, and given the nature of Windows Phone applications, you should follow this methodology.

The solution to your problem - **callbacks**. You can easily refactor your function to something like this:

```
public void GetString(string url, Action<string> onCompletion = null)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (onCompletion != null)
                onCompletion(e.Result);
        };
    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
}
```

This makes it relatively easy to use and trigger an action when it is completed. There is another way to do this as well, and that is - **async/await**. You will need to install the [Bcl.Async](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) package through NuGet:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Bcl.Async -Pre
```

It would let you do this:

```
public async Task<string> DownloadString(string url)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    return await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
}
```

Still, though, it will be bound to the asynchronous model, just wrapped in a different manner and the thread will be waiting to get the string before returning it back to the caller.

Comment: Just a note. The latter code snippet can ONLY work with VS 2012, even if it does work with .net 4.0, since it uses C#5.0